# iFrame layout and scrolling problems

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, layout

I am developing a site to use internally at our company.
As such, seo/optimization, etc are no problems due to it being run off local machines rather than web.

What I am trying to do is have a menu at the left (250px wide) that when clicked, opens a second menu next to it. When an item in this menu is clicked, it opens in a frame to the side of the second menu. If you look at the attached picture, it will give a better understanding of the layout.

http://rhinoaustralia.com/application/layoutProblems.jpg

I have put the basic site here:
http://rhinoaustralia.com/application/

(note that content is missing and only a few things work but I am trying to get the layout working first).
The css files can be found through firebug, etc.

What there is is a single page containing the first menu that has an iframe next to it. When someone clicks on a menu item, it opens a new page next to it. This new page also has a menu with an iframe next to it, so that when something in this menu is clicked, it shows in the new iframe.

This sort of works but I am having issues with getting the iframes to be the full screen and adjusting to different screen sizes. For some reason, in IE it also doesnt hide the borders.

Maybe there is a better way to do this other than nested iframes?

This is the main page/first page:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">

<div id="header" style="background-color:#222;">
    <h1>Rhino Australia Rugby Union</h1></div>

    <div id="menu" style="background-color:#222;width:250px;float:left;">
      <ul class="ca-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="rugby-union-scrum-menu.html" target="iframe_rugby-union-menu">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/collision-king.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Scrum & <br/>Breakdown</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  href="rugby-union-tackle-bag-menu.html" target="iframe_rugby-union-menu">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/low-bag-grip-and-rip.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Tackle Pads <br/> & Bags</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rugby-union-balls-menu.html" target="iframe_rugby-union-menu">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/vortex-pro.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Balls</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rugby-union-training-equipment-menu.html" target="iframe_rugby-union-menu">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/rhino-body-armour.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Training <br/> Equipment</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="rugby-union-accessory-menu.html" target="iframe_rugby-union-menu">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/water-bottle-carrier-metal.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Accessories</h2>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div id="content" style="background-color:#222; color:#FFF;float:left; width:80%; height:700px ">
    <iframe src="rugby-union-scrum.html" name="iframe_rugby-union-menu" width="100%" height="90%" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

And heres the new page that opens in the iFrame:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%">

    <div id="menu" style="background-color:#222;height:400px;width:300px;float:left;">
      <ul class="ca-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="bulldog-sled.html" target="iframe_rugby-union">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/scrum-sled.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Scrum Sled <br/> Machine</h2>
                            <h3 class="ca-sub">$7080</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a  href="collision-king.html" target="iframe_rugby-union">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/collision-king.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Collision King</h2>
                            <h3 class="ca-sub">$3590</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="ca-icon"><img src="images/rugby-union/one-man-portable-scrum.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt=""/></span>
                        <div class="ca-content">
                            <h2 class="ca-main">Portable Scrum <br/> Machine</h2>
                            <h3 class="ca-sub">$2770</h3>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    <div id="content" style="background-color:#222; color:#FFF;float:left; width:800px; height:700px">
    <iframe src="rugby-union.html" name="iframe_rugby-union" width="100%" height="90%" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" onload="" allowtransparency="false">></iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking using iFrames for this feature is not the best idea, as what essentially is happening is it's still filling 100% width of the iFrame div, as the CSS is telling it to, but at lower screen sizes, the second iFrame doesn't have room to fit and disappears.

Perhaps you could just do this by placing the assets inside the divs locally? Or, for a sleeker solution, try using the jQuery Mega Menu library: http://designingmedia.com/html/fbar/?theme=FHMM

Good luck!